# php call to undefined function (beginner on classes)

Tags: php

I have 2 files index.php and class_lib.php.

Here is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
    charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>OOP in PHP</title>
    <?php include("class_lib.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
        <?php
            $adrian = new person();
            $jimmy = new person;

            $adrian = set_name('adrian de cleir');
            $jimmy = set_name('jimmy darmady');

            echo $adrian->get_name();

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

and the file with the class

```
<?php
    class person {

    var $name;
           function set_name($new_name) {
                      $this->name = $new_name;
                   }
           function get_name() {
                      return $this->name;
                    }



    }
?>
```

When I load the page I get 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function set_name() in /var/www/php_learning_testing/index.php on line 15

Thanks for the help, its something silly im sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set_name` doesn't exist in the global scope but only off the object, you're doing it right with `get_name`.

```
        $adrian = new person();
        $jimmy = new person;

        $adrian->set_name('adrian de cleir');
        $jimmy->set_name('jimmy darmady');

        echo $adrian->get_name();
```

Your existing code (should `set_name` actually exist and return a value), would simply overwrite the objects `person` with the return value of `set_name`. Whenever you're calling non-static class methods, you always need to reference the instance.

Comment: sorry I dont really follow (just learning OOP for the first time), whats the difference between `get_name` and `set_name` in this situation, in terms of the fact that Im doing right with `get_name`? How do I reference the instance?

Comment: `$adrian->` is the difference, by prefixing it with the object reference (`$adrian`), you are calling the method within that class :)

Answer (score 1):

In the lines

```
$adrian = set_name('adrian de cleir');
$jimmy = set_name('jimmy darmady');
```

you need to call the methods on the objects:

```
$adrian->set_name('adrian de cleir');
$jimmy->set_name('jimmy darmady');
```

Comment: Thank you but now I get, Call to a member function get_name() on a non-object in /var/www/php_learning_testing/index.php on line 18 . How is this on a non object?

Answer (score 0):

for jimmy you have $jimmy = new person;
you should have

```
$jimmy = new person();
```

then to call a class method you do

```
$jimmy->set_name('bla');
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set public before the functions. Also replace var in to private. So far I know, var doesn't exist in php ;)